# Android - launcher icon doesn't reappear after manual uninstall

Tags: android, android-manifest, launcher

The launcher icon of my app is not showing on any homescreens of my device, even though it's running. Going into app info, I can see that it is displaying the correct launcher icon.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks as follows:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SelectRoomScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

[Screenshot of mipmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTgsa.png)

[Screenshot of where it should appear next to My Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJwUe.png)

As far as I can see, it *should* work. I've also tried adjusting the intent filter (removing any line except NDEF_DISCOVERED, HOME and LAUNCHER) but I'm either given an error or nothing is changing. What am I not seeing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, roundIcon is missing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Note">

    <activity android:name=".activity.NoteActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"></activity>


</application>
```

Comment: I've put `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` now but that didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Have you edited something recently inside the manifest? Anyway I am gonna post mine to let you confront with your. Be sure there is the file inside your mipmap folder, maybe you deleted it

Comment: When you say that icon doesn't appear, what do you mean? On your "device desktop" appears the name but not the icon?

Comment: No, neither the name nor the icon appears. If I couldn't run it or find the app info I wouldn't even know that it is installed.

Comment: So you cannot see it in setting->apps? Could you post a screen of your "not appearing"

Comment: It is in settings -> apps and from there I can uninstall it or force it to stop. I just can't access it from anywhere since the launch icon doesn't appear unlike when you usually run an app from AndroidStudio.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of where it should appear on my device and where my other application does appear reliably if that's what you asked for?

Comment: You said to haven't edited anything, so it's difficult to get the solution. I've never had this problem, too. I'd suggest you to unistall the app, create a new project in AndroidStudio copying ONLY class file, then install your app. But before try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I'll see if that helps. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Oh I've tried it on two different devices already, same problem :')

Comment: At least now we know that isn't your device the problem. Try my tips, let me know :-)